# Php. как правильно подставить в скрипт?

Tags: php

```
$slovo = "about acne";
$slovo = str_replace(' ', '+', $slovo); 
$slovo = str_replace('-', '+', $slovo); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mydomain.com/xlon.php?q='.$slovo.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
echo "".$result ."";
```

как сделать так, чтобы url (http://mydomain.com/xlon.php?q=) брался из txt файла

**Example:**

```
$bar = fopen 'url.txt';
$slovo = "about acne";
$slovo = str_replace(' ', '+', $slovo); 
$slovo = str_replace('-', '+', $slovo); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$bar.''.$ttt2.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
echo "".$result ."";


$bar = fopen 'url.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$bar.''.$ttt2.'');
```

url.txt

mydomain.com/xlon.php?q=

В php не очень. поэтому прошу подправить меня

Comment: file_get_contents() для чтения файла. И вместо `str_replace(' ', '+', $slovo); ` используйте `urlencode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не очень понял работу скрипта. Если я правильно понял, то `$slovo` берется из файла, ок

```
//СЧИТЫВАЕМ ИЗ ФАЙЛА
$fp = fopen('counter.txt', "r"); // Открываем файл в режиме чтения
$slovo='';
if ($fp)while (!feof($fp))$slovo = $slovo.fgets($fp, 999); else exit('ERROR!!!');
fclose($fp);
unset($fp);
echo $slovo;
//

//КОДИРУЕМ В URL
$slovo = urlencode($slovo); 
//
//ДАЛЬШЕ ВАШ КОД КОТОРЫЙ ВАМ ТРЕБУЕТСЯ, В ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ $slovo ВНУТРЕННОСТИ ФАЙЛА counter.txt
```

PHP Язык интересный да) если будут замечены недочеты, предупреждения могу подправить если это важно...

Если что-то пояснить то обьясню...

Можно использовать `file_get_contents` там вообще просто и считается более оптимизированнее.